# How to POST selected elements in the jQuery Chosen Multiselect

Tags: jquery, forms, multi-select, spring-form

I have a spring based form in order to POST my user registration. Recently, I had to update my form to allow users a project selection. This selection needs a multiselect because it can be more than one option.

My chosen select is like this:

```
<select name="projects" data-placeholder="Click to choose your project(s)" multiple class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="AA">AA</option>
    <option value="BB">BB</option>
    <option value="CC">CC</option>
</select>
```

I specified the name attribute to send the param but the behaviour is not the expected one:

```
projects    AA
projects    BB
```

The post sends the param twice. How can I do it to send something like.. projects: AA,BB ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the standard way to pass values as an array:

```
<select name="projects[]" ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution worked for me. Would you mind to tell me where I could find some documentation about this?

Comment: Couldn't find any for your framework but if it worked it's because your framework recognizes this convention and automatically does the parsing into an array.